# Domino subform not passing field value to JAVA agent

Tags: java, arguments, lotus-domino, subform

I have this Domino subform to collect user search input :

```
<form id="search-form" method="GET" action="<Computed Value>">
       <input type="hidden" name="OpenDocument" value="1"/>
       <input type="hidden" name="SearchTop" value="1"/>
       <input type="text" size="15" name="searchterm" id="searchterm" value="" class="text"/>
       <button type="submit" id="submit-search" value="GO" name="submit-search"></button>
</form>
```

Following URL is generated after user hits submit button :

```
   /search-results?OpenDocument=1&SearchTop=1&Bsearchterm=DUMMYSEARCH&submit-search=GO
```

URL processing java agent receives hidden field values(OpenDocument=1 & SearchTop=1) but NOT the actual search term(searchterm=DUMMYSEARCH) entered by user.

```
   curdoc.hasItem("searchterm") does not have searchitem field.
```

Any n all help is really appreciated.

### Thanks

Java agent processing Submit button

```
public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {
    private SearchTypes type;
    public void NotesMain() {
        Session session = null;
        AgentContext agentContext = null;
        Database db = null;
        Document curdoc = null;
        RichTextItem rt = null;
        try {
            session = getSession();
            agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
            db = agentContext.getCurrentDatabase();
            curdoc = agentContext.getDocumentContext();
                        
            if (curdoc.hasItem("searchterm"))
            {
                System.out.println("Searching for : " + 
                curdoc.getItemValueString("searchterm")); 
            }       
            String searchString = curdoc.getItemValueString("searchterm");
            this.type = determineSearchType(curdoc);
            String searchTop = curdoc.getItemValueString("SearchTop");
```

Comment: Unless there's a lot more going on than you're telling us about, you wouldn't expect to find an item with that name. URL arguments generally need to be parsed from Request_Content or Request_Content_Decoded. You need to show your code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Richard.

Comment: Just added java code processing Submit button to original post.

Comment: You are using an ?OpenDocument URL.  I don't get why you have ?OpenDocument=1. That's not normal Domino syntax. ?OpenDocument doesn't take an arguemnt, It just opens an existing document at the node specified in the preceding part of the URL. Is your agent a webQueryOpen agent?